# Images path save in database

Tags: php

I need some help to display images altogether in a popup window ,which paths are already saved in a database. If  anybody give me the actual code in php it will very much 
helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Main page:

```
<a href="imshow.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" target="_blank">
   Open in new window
</a>
```

imshow.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Image Details</title></head>
<body>
  <?php
      $path=...//read from database using $_REQUEST['id']
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $path;?>" alt="" />
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is reference site 
http://www.zenphoto.org/showcase/pl-photographies.jpg.php
download code from there